# Java with MS SQL?

Tags: java, sql-server, database

I am new in Java world. I worked before with .NET environment with `MS SQL database`, I would like to ask if I can still use `MS SQL database` with Java? and what tools do I need to proceed with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These days, you can use just about any database you want. Microsoft provides JDBC drivers for your use. You can get everything you need here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724

This link will allow you to download the JDBC driers an has usage info.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the link to download: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724